# How to interpret coefficients in polynomial linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, polynomial

The equation below stands for multiple linear regression model.

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \cdots+ \beta_n X_n + \epsilon$$

The regression coefficients ($\beta$) are interpreted as the effect of each variable ($X$) on $Y$, if all of the other explanatory variables are held constant [(Siegel & Wagner, 2022)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/regression-coefficient#:%7E:text=Interpreting%20the%20Regression,are%20held%20constant.). The polynomial linear regression model is represented by the equation below:

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 X^2 + \cdots+ \beta_n X^n + \epsilon$$

How do we interpret the coefficients of such model? The notion of holding only one variable constant (e.g., $X^2$ increases while $X^3$ is held constant) seems impossible.

Comment: Usually, if you wish to interpret coefficients, you use a more suitable basis for the polynomials.  Often, *orthogonal polynomials* offer the possibility of an interpretation.  You can always compute the change in the predicted value by varying $X,$ but the result will depend potentially on *all* the coefficients as well as the starting value of $X.$